# Visual Studio 2013 Enable Custom Properties of Ribbon Control

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, ribbon-control

I am using "Office Ribbon" control in my Winform project (Also known as Windows Ribbon control)
Control src: http://officeribbon.codeplex.com/

How can I enable red highlighted area in Visual Studio 2013, which is shown at bottom of Properties

In Visual Studio 2010 & 2012, it was appearing when I select a Panel in Ribbon control, as following.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on property grid and choose commands.

[image]